# Makefile: execute all statements in a subtarget before going to the next subtarget

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
b:
    sleep 2 && echo b1
    sleep 2 && echo b2
    sleep 2 && echo b3

a:
    sleep 2 && echo a1
    sleep 2 && echo a2
    sleep 2 && echo a3

all: | a b
    sleep 2 && echo all
```

I want subtargets a and b executed sequentially in a parallel build and add `|` before them. But instead of having something like

```
sleep 2 && echo a1
a1
sleep 2 && echo a2
a2
sleep 2 && echo a3
a3
sleep 2 && echo b1
b1
sleep 2 && echo b2
b2
sleep 2 && echo b3
b3
sleep 2 && echo all
all
```

after calling `make all -j3`, I get

```
sleep 2 && echo a1
sleep 2 && echo b1
a1
b1
sleep 2 && echo a2
sleep 2 && echo b2
a2
b2
sleep 2 && echo a3
sleep 2 && echo b3
b3
a3
sleep 2 && echo all
all
```

Is there a way to enforce the behaviour I expected without putting all commands in each target is a separate script? I mean, that all subtargets of `all` would be executed in order, but their subtargets could be done in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying `all : | a b` means that both `a` and `b` must complete before `all`, but you have said nothing about `a` and `b` in relation to *each other*.

If you want to run `a` before `b`, then you have to declare:

```
b: a
```

Comment: So, if I want a target `rebuild`, that would first execute target `clean`, and then `all`, but without making `all` depend on `clean`, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @InnotKauker `rebuild: clean; $(MAKE) all` should work (via recursive invocation).

Comment: Etan is right.  Recursive is about the only way to do this.